# How do i divide my minute data into tables containing each month in Timescaledb (PostgreSQL extension)

Tags: postgresql, time-series, timescaledb

I am new to timescaledb and I want to store one minute ohlcv ticks for each stock in the table. There are 1440 ticks generated daily for one stock and  43200 ticks a month. I have a 100 assets whose ticks I would like to store every month and basically have the tables divide every 30 days or so, so that I dont have to build complex logic for this division. Any suggestions on how this can be done with timescale DB.

Currently, the way I am doing it is

- Take incoming tick (ex timestamp **1535090420**)
- Round its timestamp to the nearest 30 day period **(1535090420/(86400 * 30)) = 592.241674383**
- Round this number to **592** and multiply by interval to get **1534464000** which is the nearest 30 day bucket inside which all the ticks should be stored So I create a table called **OHLC_1534464000** if not exists and add the ticks there
- Is there a better way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, it sounds like you just want a table partitioned by 30 day intervals that will automatically know which table to put incoming data into based on the timestamp. This is exactly the functionality TimescaleDB's [hypertables](https://docs.timescale.com/v0.11/using-timescaledb/hypertables).

You can create your table using the following syntax:

`SELECT create_hypertable('ohlc', 'timestamp', chunk_time_interval => interval '30 days');`

This will create 30 day chunks (just Postgres tables under the hood) and transparently place each tick in the appropriate chunk based on its timestamp. It will automatically create a new chunk once a tick passing the current 30 day period comes in. You can just insert and query on the main table (`ohlc`) as though it were a single Postgres table.

Comment: OMG! I wish I could upvote you 10 times! Thank you sooooo much man